# Picking the right domain name

Tags: domains

The issue I have is that my family name is relatively common, and I'm pretty awful at coming up with names.
Yet I'd like to register a decent domain name that SEO won't hate.

The point of the site would be about programming in general, and some things about android development.
So I was thinking about registering fmdev.org (or .net any input on which of the two is more interesting is always appreciated).
The reason for not picking a .com despite its obvious advantages is that I'm a bit leery about how the USA has been acting lately in regards to privacy/ownership of people from another country when they just own hosting in the USA/having a .com domain name).

I first thought about going for the full blown development instead of dev, but that seemed a bit on the long side. And I'm guessing google's search engine will pick up on the meaning. (or am I mistaken in that?)

Any advice/input is always appreciated.

Comment: You do realise that .org and .net are as vulnerable as .com to intervention by the US government?

Comment: No, I'm not. As far as I've read Erik Barnett only made statements about .com (and as I just now read .net).

Comment: @FredricMichielsen "Technically" the US goverment can do anything, just because the IANA root is hosted and serviced by a US company. And there were attempts in that direction, to nuke whole TLDs, as requested by some plaintiffs considering to be affected by acts of terrors from those countries, see https://www.icann.org/en/system/files/files/appellants-brief-26aug15-en.pdf (it was not granted obviously). If it "legally" can do it, and what would be the consequences, are a matter of numerous books and articles, and remains fiction for now.

Answer (score 1):

Domains are cheap so you can have both and there aren't any problems with registering and owning .com domains here (I'm from Poland).

I'd say go for the shorter one (fmdev also sounds nice).

When it comes to small sites the content is much more important than the URL as long as it's short and easy to remember.

Comment: Any input on the .com/.org/.net portion and what's best? The original intent of commercial/organisation seems to have been lost over the last few years.

Comment: Sure - .org is the one that kept most of its original intent. A lot of non-profit or community-based (by community for community) sites use .org as their main domain (some of them have also .com).

Of course it's best to have all of them, but .net and .com are probably enough (and if you don't want to spend too much money .com should do alone for a commercial website).

Answer (score 0):

Domains and Extensions do not play a major role in SEO although they are necessary if you wan't a perfectly optimized site. I don't see any reason why you should not have a .com domain. If I were you and had the money, I would have booked all TLDs for fmdev as it secures your brand which is much more essential in your case.

Comment: Domain names do play an important role in SEO, especially for Google. They're trying to reduce its value but it still currently has a lot of SEO value and probably will do so for some time.